# Is there any other approach for refreshing page in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I spent 2 days to find out how to manage the way that pages are refreshed after the login system is signed in or signed out properly.

Here is the problem: My login system works fine until now, but there is a trivial issue. Thing is that when I try to log in to come to the home page, I need my home page will be loaded fully after redirected (and that is like refreshing the page when you hit the F5 key on the keyboard, or when you click on the link of the navigation) and so when I finish my log in session to come back to log in page. I've tried some approaches:

1. Put reload() function when init the page in the Home controller, like this:

   function HomeController(UserService, $rootScope,$route,$window) {
       var vm = this;

   ```
   vm.user = null;
   vm.allUsers = [];
   vm.deleteUser = deleteUser;
   vm.logout = logout;

   function loading(){
       $state.reload();
   }
   initController();

   function initController() {
       loading();
   }
   ```

   but it ends up an infinite loop
2. Use the function in Login Controller:: window.location.href =""
   but results in the same output as : location.path();

   function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService,$route) {
       var vm = this;

   ```
   vm.login = login;

   (function initController() {
       // reset login status
       AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
   })();

   function login() {
       vm.dataLoading = true;
       AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
           if (response.success) {
               AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
            $window.location.reload();
            //$window.location.href="/"; 
            $location.path('/'); // send to home page
           } else {
               FlashService.Error(response.message);
               vm.dataLoading = false;
           }
       });
   };
   ```
3. Both reload() and window.location.href in Login Controller:

   function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService,$route) {
       var vm = this;

   ```
   vm.login = login;

   (function initController() {
       // reset login status
       AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
   })();

   function login() {
       vm.dataLoading = true;
       AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
           if (response.success) {
               AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
            $window.location.reload();
            $window.location.href="/"; 
            //$location.path('/'); // send to home page
           } else {
               FlashService.Error(response.message);
               vm.dataLoading = false;
           }
       });
   };
   ```

but it loads the destination first then reload that page no matter what I put the order of these sentences, so it is load twice.

None of these attempts seem right, so I need some suggestions from you guys, are there any solutions to such a problem? Thanks!

Comment: We are working on a similar system (i.e. Login page at one side, working page(s) at the other). Our solution is trivial and works perfecrtly: There are two `ng-if` within the `index.html`, both depending on a scope variable `logged_in` (true or false). The displayed page (actually, included) is the one that matches the value of that variable. Voila!!!

Comment: What routing do you use in angular? is it `ui-router`? or something else?